# rate of convergence of integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume that $0<f_n(x)\to 0$ pointwise at rate $1/n$ and $f_n$ is integrable.
Can I say that $\int f_n(x)dx\to 0$ at the same rate $1/n$ ?. If not, what assumptions needed so that the conclusion is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you can find an integer $N$ and integrable functions $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n}a(x)\leq f_{n}(x)\leq\frac{1}{n}b(x)\text{ for }n\geq N.
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\int a(x)dx\leq\int\frac{a(x)}{n}dx\leq\int f_{n}(x)dx\leq\int\frac{b(x)}{n}dx=\frac{1}{n}\int b(x)dx.
$$